# Visual Studio Community 2022: how to set a SOLUTION-WIDE include path, library links, etc.?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I can go through projects and do the following: right-click-->Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Additional Include Directories, and add the directories I wish.

However, there is an "inherited values" section on that dialog.  I'd like to set a bunch of include and lib directories, pre-processor defines, and libraries to link to for the entire solution at once.  I would have thought this would be a tab on the solution's properties but it isn't.

Comment: Use a props file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170

Comment: Thx Alan, looks like the exact right answer.  If you answer thusly I'll mark it as right.  Otherwise I'll answer my own question with a more detailed walkthrough of the solution you've pointed to.